# Warning: version 3.4.4 of ‘ggplot2’ masked by 3.3.6

Tags: ggplot2, ggally

I am trying to load the package GGally and get the error message: Warning: version 3.4.4 of ‘ggplot2’ masked by 3.3.6 in C:/Users/gauri/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1Error: package ‘ggplot2’ 3.3.6 was found, but >= 3.4.4 is required by ‘GGally’.

I have tried to update ggpot2 but I still get the same error.